# Unity3d shader e -f convert to glsl

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, hlsl, cg

I am trying to convert to a shader in `Unity3D` to normal glsl shader.

The code is :

```
Out = lerp(To, In, saturate((Distance - Range) / max(Fuzziness, e-f)));
```

I know the `lerp` need to be convert to `mix` and `saturate` to `clamp(xxx, 0.0, 1.0)`.

But I don't know how to convert the `e - f` part in the code above.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What is `e` and `f`?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@10.3/manual/Replace-Color-Node.html

Comment: here is the codes

Comment: I found this myself but that doesn't answer my question. What is `e` and `f`?

Answer (score -1):

You can see the code generated by your graph : right click on any node -> Show generated code. For this node the glsl function generated is :

```
void Unity_ReplaceColor_float(float3 In, float3 From, float3 To, float Range, out float3 Out, float Fuzziness)
{
    float Distance = distance(From, In);
    Out = lerp(To, In, saturate((Distance - Range) / max(Fuzziness, 1e-5f)));
}
```

Comment: This is HLSL, not glsl, so this doesn't really answer the question about how to port to glsl.